# Reselect with an array causing component to always render

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

I'm using reselect to query my state and props.
When I add a log statement to my component, I can see that it is being rendered over and over again.

If I return a **find** (non-array, one object) from the `getFiltered` method I see that it doesn't render over and over again. If I return a **filter** from the `getFiltered` method I see that it does render over and over again.

I assume its to do with some array === array going on somewhere. How do I fix it? I've tried using lodash's isEqual as per the [documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-why-is-my-selector-recomputing-when-the-input-state-stays-the-same). I'm feeding the result of getFiltered into my state. It looks like the state thinks its changing for some reason

```
export const getProjects = state => state.availability.projects.list;

export const getProjectId = (state, props) => props.project.id;

// WORKS! - Don't see re-render log statements
export const getFiltered = createSelector([getProjects, getProjectId],
(projects, projectId) => projects.find(project => project));

// Doesn't work - I do see re-render statements in the console
export const getFiltered = createSelector([getProjects, getProjectId],
(projects, projectId) => projects.filter(project => project));
```

Comment: Reselect should memoize the result of the function and not run it again if the input hasn't changed. Check that the values returned by `getProjects` and `getProjectId` are not changing.

Comment: It looks like the output of getFiltered is causing the re-render rather than the input. I have the same code for find and filter. And filter causes a re-render

Comment: Yes, but with Reselect, if the input does not change, the function isn't even run, so the output cannot possibly change. That's why I suggested to look at that. With `find` you are returning the exact same object, that's why you don't see the re-render. `filter`, instead, returns a new array every time it runs, but Reselect should ensure that the function is not run at all if the input values are the same.

Comment: Sounds like - as you said, it should only run the function if the inputs are changing. When i console log them they look the same. Maybe because its an array as an input, it looks different each time?

Comment: The only other peculiarity that im doing is running this createSelector for multiple of the same components. So i have a mapStateToProps for each instance

Comment: Are the input selectors memoized with Reselect as well? Check if they are using one of the array methods that return a new array, such as `map`, `reduce`, `slice`, etc. Can you paste more of the code, including the react component that uses this?

Comment: @SebastianPattenn How did you solve it? I'm facing the exact problem